# Products are not showing in category Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category-products

I am facing an issue that categories are not showing products. Some categories are showing product but I assigned 3 products to a category and it's showing me only 1 and some categories are not showing a single product. I checked

> 1. Product status as Enabled
> 2. Product Visibility as catalog, search
> 3. Product quantity > 0
> 4. Product inventory as In Stock
> 5. Product price > 0

For category :

> 1. Is Active as Yes
> 2. Display Mode as Product Only
> 3. In the category products tab, it's showing all the products that are assigned to the category.

But it is not showing on the category page on front-end.

I am using SM Market theme.

Can anyone help to get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check below list

If below things are done.

> 1.General->Status = Enabled
>
> 2.general->Visibility = Catalog,Search
>
> 3.Inventory->Qty > 0
>
> 4.Inventory->Stock Availability = In Stock
>
> 5.Websites = checking your site
>
> 6.Catgories = checking your category.

You have to remove **var folder** from root and try commands using cli:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Clear browser cache and try again.

Comment: Removing var folder will not effect my site???

Comment: Normally it doesn't effect unless there is some error. You can first try on local site then try on live for safety.

Comment: Hi i tried above commands. After running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` , i get Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9611362 bytes).

Comment: Found solution for error. used `php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and change 6G to what you want. After that run the second command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`. Now its working fine...

Comment: If you have Varnish make sure page is purged

Comment: Thats stupid. If you remove the **var** folder then you *might* delete important backups and the customer sessions if they are setup to be stored on the filesystem !!

Answer (score 1):

For me its due to following error:-

```
Base table or view not found 1146 table 'inventory_stock_1' doesn't exist
```

solution is to create view may be on server due to permission to DB user this view not created, need to create like following:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbusername`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`dbname`.`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `dbname`.`catalog_product_entity` `product` on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add your product programmatically, don't forget to add :

```
$product->setWebsiteIds(array($yourWebsiteId))
```

or it will not appears in front website.

Answer (score 0):

Please check product salable quantity, This issue can come if the salable quantity is zero to fix that please make sure you have a view table inventory_stock_1 in your database.

This issue can come if you have migrated database from one to another so that time you may be missed to migrate view tables.