# Magento 2 is not showing product in categroy pages

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.2, reindex

I use Magento 2.2.2 and since yesterday I can't see any products in category pages. products are available individually but not available in any category pages

***I've done these solutions but still, it's not working.***

```
1- php bin/magento indexer:reset
2- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
3- php bin/magento indexer:status
```

*shows that some indexes are always in processing state*

**note. reindex takes almost 20 or 30 minutes which is not usual for us.** 

**note. sometimes products just appear for like one minute after the reindex and they disappear again.**

Answer (score 0):

Check below list

If below things are done.

```
1.General->Status = Enabled

2.general->Visibility = Catalog,Search

3.Inventory->Qty > 0

4.Inventory->Stock Availability = In Stock

5.Websites = checking your site

6.Catgories = checking your category.
```

You have to remove var folder from root and try commands using cli:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Clear browser cache and try again.

[Products are not showing in category Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135814/products-are-not-showing-in-category-magento-2)

Comment: I already check this. and it's still not working

Comment: you refer this :-  http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/07/19/magento-products-not-showing-in-categories/